# Error Code: 1234. Incorrect usage/placement of 'SQL_BUFFER_RESULT'

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a simple view which counts some data and brings it up, but MySQL is throwing this error:

> Error Code: 1234. Incorrect usage/placement of 'SQL_BUFFER_RESULT'

Code:

```
        CREATE or replace
        ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
        DEFINER = `root`@`%` 
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    VIEW `view_test` AS
        SELECT 
            a.uf AS uf,
            CAST(a.empresas_total AS UNSIGNED) AS total_21,
           CAST(b.empresas_total AS UNSIGNED) AS total_20,
          (select CAST(SUM(a.empresas_total - b.empresas_total) AS DECIMAL)) AS DIF_total_2020
 FROM
        base.tableA a
        left join  base.tableB b
        on
        a.uf=b.uf
        
    GROUP BY a.uf;
```

This is not working.

When delete the line

```
          (select CAST(SUM(a.empresas_total - b.empresas_total) AS DECIMAL)) AS DIF_total_2020
```

it works fine.
The view is created and fully functional.

Can anyone spot my error?
Actually, by doing the select itself, it goes OK. it only ends in a error when creating the view.

Comment: What is `SQL_BUFFER_RESULT` session variable value?

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION()` show?

Comment: SQL_BUFFER_RESULT = InnoDB

Comment: SELECT VERSION() = 5.7.36-log

Comment: Anyone? please help! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what is going on:
The line

```
 (select CAST(SUM(
```

is the problem, obviously. But the problem is that when creating the view, somehow the server miss the `SQL_BUFFER_RESULT` in there, as it create the view automatically with the SQL_BUFFER_RESULT in the first line of the select, and it is valid for EVERY field described after that.

The solution was to rewrite the line by removing the select and making it sum without it.

```
   SUM((CAST(a.empresas_total AS DECIMAL))-(CAST(b.empresas_total AS DECIMAL))) AS DIF_empresas_total
```

So, the view was created using a single statement of SQL_BUFFER_RESULT and worked:

```
CREATE or replace
        ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
        DEFINER = `root`@`%` 
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    VIEW `view_test` AS
        SELECT SQL_BUFFER_RESULT
            a.uf AS uf,
            CAST(a.empresas_total AS UNSIGNED) AS total_21,
           CAST(b.empresas_total AS UNSIGNED) AS total_20,
            SUM((CAST(a.empresas_total AS DECIMAL))-(CAST(b.empresas_total AS DECIMAL))) AS DIF_empresas_total
 FROM
        base.tableA a
        left join  base.tableB b
        on
        a.uf=b.uf
        
    GROUP BY a.uf;
```

Worked fine!
Thanks.